# Sonata Admin embed forms one-to-many does not persist

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I've been trying to implement embed forms in Sonata Admin Bundle 2.0,  Sonata User Bundle 2.0 and Symfony 2.0.16 (yes, I know it's kind of old right now)  and after reading a lot of forum posts and manual I could be able to implement it... but just at form level, it can't display data in edition mode, or persist it in creation mode.

Being more expecific, I'm trying to make work a relationship between an User entity (from Sonata User Bundle) with an Email entity, in an one-to-many relationship (one User has many Emails, or just one). So in the User form is gonna have one or more emails forms dynamically embeded, which seems to be working, but are disconnected with the email table.

systemUser is pointing to the table user. I got to change it because I'm using PostgreSQL and word is reserved.

**UserAdmin.php**

```
<?php

class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
    // more code

        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Groups')
                ->add('groups', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Profile')
                ->add('dateOfBirth', 'date', array('required' => false))
                ->add('firstname', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('lastname', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('website', 'url', array('required' => false))
                ->add('locale', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('timezone', null, array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            ->with('Emails')
                ->add('emails', 'collection', array(
                    'label' => 'Emails',
                    'required' => true,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'id',
                    'targetEntity'=> 'MyProject\xBundle\Entity\Email',
                    'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'user'),
                )
            )
        ;
    // more code ...
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var array emails
     */
    protected $emails;

    /**
     * @var string user
     */
    protected $user;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add emails
     *
     * @param MyProject\xBundle\Email $email
     */
    public function addEmails(\MyProject\xBundle\Entity\Email $email)
    {
        $this->emails[] = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Get emails
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getEmails()
    {
        return $this->emails;
    }

    /**
     * Set emails
     *
     * @param  $emails
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setEmails($emails)
    {
        $this->$emails = $emails;

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $email->setUser($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

**Email.php**

```
<?php

class Email
{
   /**
    * @var SystemUser
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="system_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    *
    */
   private $systemUser;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->systemUser = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   /**
    *
    * @param MyProject\xBundle\Entity\User $systemUser
    */
   public function setSystemUser(\MyProject\xBundle\Entity\User $systemUsers = null)
   {
       $this->systemUser = $systemUser;

       return $this;
   }

   /**
    * Get systemUser
    *
    * @return MyProject\xBundle\Entity\User
    */
   public function getSystemUser()
   {
       return $this->systemUser;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your approach needs a 'forward' relationship from the `User` to the `Email` entity, otherwise the admin doesn't know what to change and persist. Change your code in `User.php` so that the `email` variable actually knows about its relationship. That means you should add something like

```
/**
 * @var array emails
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Email", mappedBy="systemUser", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $emails;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already find a similar case in the Symfony forum. http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=35914

But then I got a couple of issues, one was that my EmailType class was not been reading at all, so displays just one field instead two. The second issue is comes when I try to save the form:  

`Expected argument of type "array", "string" given`

What I found was the address field was been sent twice: first as a string, then as an array.

Comment: Anyway, seems like all of this is a waste of time because Symfony 2.0 doesn't treat inverse relationships properly. The fix was implemented properly in the new Form class in Symfony 2.1.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3539
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1540

So I ought to upgrade the framework to get the job done (and because 2.0 series will have support till this month).

Comment: Just another thing: `mappedBy="systemUser"` is wrong in the Doctrine annotation, `mappedBy` targets to an class property, not to any database table. Using `systemUser` leads to an error.

Comment: @user1595642 I would suggest that you try `sonata_type_collection` instead of `collection` though, I never got that one to work. What's the error?

Comment: Actually `sonata_type_collection` was my first choice. It just does not work. No message error or warning at all. Email form is completely ignored, `collection` instead display the form. Right now I'm in the process to update Symfony 2.0 to 2.1. I hope that fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did, but after upgrade many times a lot of bundles, the thing stop working one year later. I left the issue as a pending task.